# How to fin and extract substring BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

A have a string column at BigQuery table for example:

| name |
| --- |
| WW_for_all_feed |
| EU_param_1_for_all_feed |
| AU_for_all_full_settings_18+ |
| WW_for_us_param_5_for_us_feed |
| WW_for_us_param_5_feed |
| WW_for_all_25+ |

and also have a list of variables, for example :

```
param_1_for_all
param_5_for_us
param_5 
full_settings
```

And if string at column "name" contains one of this substrings needs to extract it :

| name | param |
| --- | --- |
| WW_for_all_feed | None |
| EU_param_1_for_all_feed | param_1_for_all |
| AU_for_all_full_settings_18+ | full_settings |
| WW_for_us_param_5_for_us_feed | param_5_for_us |
| WW_for_us_param_5_feed | param_5 |
| WW_for_all_25+ | None |

I want to try regexp and replace, but don't know pattern for find substring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below

```
select name, param
from your_table
left join params 
on regexp_contains(name, param)
```

if apply to sample data as in your question

```
with your_table as (
  select 'WW_for_all_feed' name union all
  select 'EU_param_1_for_all_feed' union all
  select 'AU_for_all_full_settings_18+' union all
  select 'WW_for_us_param_5_for_us_feed' union all
  select 'WW_for_all_25+' 
), params as (
  select 'param_1_for_all' param union all
  select 'param_5_for_us' union all
  select 'full_settings' 
)
```

output is

[image]

> but I have an another issue (updated question) If one of params is substring for another?

use below then

```
select name, string_agg(param order by length(param) desc limit 1) param
from your_table
left join params 
on regexp_contains(name, param)
group by name
```

if applied to your updated data sample  - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I have an another issue (updated question) 
If one of params is substring for another?

Comment: see update in answer